# Why is xmgrace ignoring my column of X data?

Tags: plot, xmgrace

I've been a longtime user of `xmgrace`/`grace`, but today I'm stumped. I have a `.dat` file that is simply two columns of space-separated `X Y` data like I'm accustomed to plotting.  But for some reason the program is only using the Y information and plotting X as the integer sequence/row numbers.  Here's a sample of the data:

```
$ cat test.dat
0.016426149 0.91780442
0.016559154 1.942617893
0.016692159 1.937870622
0.016758662 2.160227537
0.016825165 1.464688301
0.016891667 2.413390636
0.017024672 2.62378788
0.017024672 2.396263838
0.01722418 2.30436182
```

but when I run `xmgrace test.dat` (or try `Data > Import > ASCII...`), the x-axis goes from 0 to 14 instead of 0.0164 to 0.0172.
I don't see any hidden characters in the file (used `:set list` in `vi`)...

If this helps: The file was originally a CSV that I exported from Excel on my Mac, and used `vi` to replace the commas with spaces.  So...there are no tabs in the file, and no Windows-style ^M's.

How do I get `xmgrace` to use my `x` information properly?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Does this happen only with that file? What if you try to copy&paste the data in another file?

Comment: @lr1985 Thanks for your reply.  That test.dat example was a copy & paste from a longer file. Interestingly if I copy & paste those numbers from this website, then it plots no problem! This suggested that I paste into an online "special character stripper", which after that I could plot as normal. And yet vi didn't show any special characters.  Very odd!

Comment: This is bizarre indeed, although unicode is a weird beast!